# how to auto fit image height and with in div.

Tags: html, css

In my case i have a image with dimensions 1587*666. and i want to fit this image in a div with height 600px and width 300px. but i am not successful to do this. any one help me with example.[image: this is a image which i have to be fit in my div]

This is a code.

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width:300px; height:600px;">
<img src="top_add.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: check css object-fit, but use background-image for divs

Answer (score 1):

Specify **image** tag width and height to **"100%"** OR **"inherit"**

inherit property set parent tag height and width.

```
 #myDiv img {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
```

**OR**

```
 #myDiv img {
        width:inherit;
        height:inherit;
    }
```

Comment: This really works fine :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

just set image to 100%.

---

**HTML**

---

```
<div id="myDiv">
<img src="top_add.png"/>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

---

```
img{
    width: 100%;
}
#myDiv{
    width:300px;
    height:600px;
}
```

*I suggest you to Don't use inline styles*

Comment: it was not working properly. because required dimensions are not get after applying this.

Comment: @mohsin_sharif57 Than you need to give height 100% as per Sandip Patel's suggetion.

Answer (score 0):

If you set width and height and one day change image it will scale in a bad way.
It's much better to put it there as a background with styles. Here's an example:

```
height: 600px;
width: 300px;
background: url('path_to_your/image.jpg'); 
background-size: cover; 
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: ok buddy i'll try this

Comment: @mohsin_sharif57 http://codepen.io/adrenalbooster/pen/GqwYvr proof of concept

Comment: ok buddy. - @Adrenalbooster